# How can I scale down this contact form section in CSS? It is taking too much space at the bottom of the webpage

Tags: html, css, contact-form

I am having trouble where I have my contact form section taking up too much space at the bottom of the webpage. I have tried using the scale tags to try to change the overall size of the form container it did not have any change on the webpage.

I have tried to change the width and height of the .section-4 and .form-container but when I change it, it throws off the other elements (for ex: the text-area size and the style="submit" sizing). Is there a better way to scale the entire section down to a smaller size without disturbing the child elements?

```css
.section-4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  bottom: -50%;
}

.form-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #e5eaff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.4rem #ccc, -0.1rem -0.1rem 0.4rem #ccc;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  perspective: 100rem;
}

.form-img {
  width: 30rem;
  background-color: rgba(50, 231, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 90px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow: -3rem 3rem 4rem #aaa;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  transform: rotateY(20deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.form-img:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2rem) rotateY(20deg);
  box-shadow: -5rem 5rem 7rem #aaa;
}

.contact-form {
  width: 45rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 3rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 3rem 3rem 4rem #aaa;
  transform: rotateY(-20deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.contact-form:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2rem) rotateY(-20deg);
  box-shadow: 5rem 5rem 7rem #aaa;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.2rem #ddd, inset -0.1rem -0.1rem 0.2rem #ddd;
}

.contact-form textarea {
  max-height: 15rem;
  min-height: 10rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 70%;
}

.contact-form input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: rgba(50, 231, 255, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.contact-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #32e7ff;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-4" id="contact">
  <h1 class="section-heading">Contact</h1>
  <div class="form-container">
  <img src="imgs/form-img.png" class="form-img">
    <form class="contact-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
      <textarea placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Ce7.png) is a screenshot of the current contact form size. It is taking all the space at the bottom of the page. I would like to scale it down.

Comment: Bearing in mind that a human needs things to be of a reasonable size if they are to type into them an alternative approach may be to have the form open up as an overlay if they click on a contact button.

Comment: jusd add `padding-bottom` in `body` or on the `parent-container` of the form.